# Simulating 4D on a 3D mean

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis, dimensional-analysis

Why if we can simulate 3D on a 2D mean, why isn't possible to simulate 4D on a 3D mean (real world)? Has someone tried?

Comment: What is the meaning of "$n$D mean"?

Comment: Here is a visualisation of a tesseract (4D-cube). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract